# Why merge commits for git flow release finish instead of fast-forward HEAD update?

Tags: git-flow

Does git flow avoid fast forward merges for better reporting?

While testing git flow I see not only the commits from my release branch on master & develop but also merge commits.  I thought I'd only see release branch commits and then a fast-forward as git adjusted master & develop to point to the new commits.

As a very simple case, I expected no merge commit requirement since no other changes appeared between the time of release branch start and finish.

**What drives the merge commit requirement or did I miss something?**

Thanks

Peter

**Scenario: Release Stabilization**

1. Create release branch (**git flow release start 100.0.0 develop**)
2. Push for collaboration (**git flow release publish 100.0.0**) (it's just me, so I'm collaborating with myself)
3. make and commit 1 change on release/100.0.0
4. Finish release (**git flow release finish**)

**RESULT**

```
local develop +3 commits to remote
  HEAD    merge tag to develop e191707
  HEAD -1 e0040cb merge from release branch
  HEAD -2 e7cdc02 release branch change

local develop +3 commits to remote
  HEAD    merge tag to develop e191707
  HEAD -1 e0040cb merge from release branch
  HEAD -2 e7cdc02 release branch change

local master + 2 commit to remote
  HEAD e0040cb merge commit 
  HEAD -1 e7cdc02 stabilization change
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that git flow uses **git merge --no-ff** as its default (see [git flow considered harmful](http://endoflineblog.com/gitflow-considered-harmful)).  I don't think that choice help improve understanding and creates unnecessary noise.  I expect us to use git flow provided we can sort out when to use *ff*